# C code with one goto label not working as expected

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point, goto

I've been asked to break down a C program which initially was just one main method with a lot of well commented segments. Each segment makes use of this same defined function string, 'die', if an error occurs. The die function uses the goto label, 'out', which shuts down the program.

After turning each one of these segments into a function which are all now called from the scaled down main method at the bottom, this goto out code of each segment no longer works. The 'out' label is within the main and the XCode compiler is telling me that the goto label hasn't been defined.

So I guess I'm asking how do I define my out label in each of these local functions, in the most efficient manner?

Here are some code snippets, all in the order/structure they appear:

Die defined

```
    #define die(msg, ...) do {                      \
(void) fprintf (stderr, msg, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
(void) fprintf (stderr, "\n");                \
goto out;                                     \
} while (0)
```

An example of a function using die

```
void createContext(void){
        context = clCreateContext (0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
        if (!context || err != CL_SUCCESS)
            die ("Error: Failed to create a compute context!");
    }
```

Finally my main, which contains the out label from die at the end

```
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    (Several functions called here)

out:
    /* Shutdown and cleanup.  */
    if (data)
        free (data);

    if (results)
        free (results);

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: goto label works only in a single function having goto in one function  and label in other is undefined

Comment: You will want to make all new functions to return error code, check it in main() and goto out there only. longjmp/setjmp is a global goto, but I don't think it's a good idea here.

Comment: Even if the use of `goto` here is bad style, the question itself is Ok. I see no reason to downvote. @H2CO3

Comment: @H2CO3, legacy code is a good enough reason to use goto sometimes. The question is not whether goto is a good idea or not.

Comment: @alk my real reason for the downvote is that this can easily be googled.

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis for you too this ^^ comment

Comment: I consulted Kernighan and Ritchie and still didn't quite get what was being said. Like I said, I am inexperienced with C for the most part and this isn't even my code. I didn't choose to use a goto!

Comment: Anyone heard the latest programming news? [Goto considered harmful](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.utexas.edu%2F~EWD%2Fewd02xx%2FEWD215.PDF&ei=fMyPUKK8Ge_U4QTYyYGYCg&usg=AFQjCNEcr4fOejRCelUl7OQ91Csi_A0CXg). Woah that's some radical opinions, lets open up the debate!

Comment: @Lundin, can't tell if you are being sarcastic or not. I hope you are and that we can stop dragging that old thing around. GOTO like everything else should be used with consideration and full understanding of the consequences.

Comment: @r_ahlskog Hint: I linked a 44 year old paper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `goto` can not span functions. If you use `goto` it has to be to a label within the same function as the `goto`.

To do a jump between functions, look up the [`setjmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp) and [`longjmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/longjmp) functions.

However, in your case since you are just jumping to exit the program, you can call `exit` directly instead. All resources (open files, allocated memory) will be released by the runtime library and the operating system.

Comment: And this exit will still permit me to use the error messages of die?

Comment: @Chucky Of course, just put it in place of the `goto`, and the `printf` calls will be executed first as usual.